# Can be a continuous function at $x=a$, but doesn't have limit at $x=a$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I know, from calculus the definition of continuity is given below:
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a).$$
So most of cases, if $f(x)$ continuous at some point, the limit also exists. However, I have a 'little silly' thought and observation like this.

Actually the definition of continuity at $x=a$ is:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon.$$

Take a look about this function:
$$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(n) = 1.$$
This is a discrete function and continu at $n=1$.

We see, for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $\delta = 1$ such that
$$|n-1| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(n)-1| = 0 < \epsilon.$$
The implication is true, since $|n-1| < \delta$ is false. **(Vacuous truth)**

But the function above doesn't have limit at $n=1$ because there is no $\delta >0$ such that
$$(n-\delta, n+\delta) \cup \mathbb{N} \not = \emptyset.$$
So $n=1$ is not accumulation point. Hence
$$\lim_{n \to 1} f(n)$$
is undefined.

Is my reason correct? Or there is a flaw in reasoning (?)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to say that I learnt this differently than the main stream definition : I learnt that the function (to be continous at $x=a$) must be defined at $x=a$ and the limits (from both sides) must exist and coincide and be equal to $f(a)$. Apparently, this is not necessary if the function is not defined left (or right) from $a$. Not sure what the main stream says if the function is only defined at $x=a$.

Comment: *"But the function above doesn't have limit at n=1"*. It does, and you've shown that it does. For all $n$ near $1$ but not equal to $1$, anything is true since there are no such $n$. Functions defined at isolated points are vacuously, but counterintuitively, continuous at those points.

Comment: @Jam Yes, this is how the main stream defines it. More confusing that the way I learnt it.

Comment: @Jam ah, thank you. Yes this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Peter, thankyou for answering my doubt